# how can i connect mongodb atlas and piplines in scrapy (python)?

Tags: python, mongodb, scrapy

i make crawler to use scarpy.
now i try to connect mongodb atlas and pipelines (scrapy).
then i made this code in pipelines.py

```
from itemadapter import ItemAdapter

from scrapy.exceptions import DropItem


from dotenv import load_dotenv
import os
from pathlib import Path  
env_path = Path('../.env')
load_dotenv(dotenv_path=env_path)

import pymongo

connection = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb+srv://{}:{}@rbscrapycluster.hzuaa.mongodb.net/myFirstDatabase?retryWrites=true&w=majority".format(os.getenv('ID'), os.getenv('PWD')))
db = connection.JeonjuDB

class JeonjueventPipeline:

    # def open_spider(self, spider):
    #     spider.logger.info("테스트 파이프라인 시작")


    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        if(item.get('index')) == ' 유관기관 소식 ':
            collection_relatedInstitutions = db.relatedInstitutions
            collection_relatedInstitutions.create_index([('link',1)],unique=True)
            collection_relatedInstitutions.insert_one(item)
       
        elif(item.get('index')) == ' 새소식 ':
            collection_issue = db.issue
            collection_issue.create_index([('link',1)],unique=True)
            collection_issue.insert_one(item)
       
        elif(item.get('index')) == ' 공연/행사 ':
            collection_events = db.events
            collection_events.create_index([('link',1)],unique=True)
            print('work well')
            print('===>', item)
            collection_events.insert_one(item)
       
        elif(item.get('index')) == ' 주간행사 ':
            collection_weeklyEvents = db.weeklyEvents
            collection_weeklyEvents.create_index([('link',1)],unique=True)
            collection_weeklyEvents.insert_one(item)
        else:
            print('not valid')
        return item
```

after i run scrapy, new db and collections is created on mongodb atlas.
but collected data didn't reach till mongodb atlas.

and when i print `item` in pipelines.py. one of collected datas was this.

```
===> {'date': '2021.02.28(일)',
 'index': ' 공연/행사 ',
 'title': "2021 상설전시 '전주 서포와 방각본 이야기'"}
```

i think `item` data structure is `dict`, but i don't know why this data can't enter in mongodb atlas :(

plz help me :)